# Get Template Part - Does not work if not in same file

Tags: php, html, wordpress

**This is a question related to *WordPress* and *Get Template Part*.**

I have set up `page.php` and `single.php` with `get_template_part` so it's easy to edit future templates.

However, I notice that two of them does not work when they are located in two different files. They only work if they are in the same file.

## Here is my page.php:

```
<?php get_template_part( 'toppbilde', 'mal' ); ?>

<article>
<?php get_template_part( 'ingress', 'm' ); ?>

<?php get_template_part( 'body', 'm' ); ?>
</article>
```

`toppbilde-mal.php` is the featured image. This works.

`ingress-m.php` **is the text before the more tag. It has the following code:**

```
<div class="clearfix">
    <div class="holder color1 whitetext centertext">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <h1 class="littluft" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                    <div class="littluft">
                        <?php 
                            // Fetch post content
                            $content = get_post_field( 'post_content', get_the_ID() );

                            $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);

                            // Get content parts
                            $content_parts = get_extended( $content );

                            // Output part before <!--more--> tag
                            echo $content_parts['main'];
                        ?> 
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`body-m.php` **is the text after the more tag. It has the following code:**

```
<?php if (!empty($content_parts['extended'])) { ?>
    <div class="clearfix">
        <div class="holder white color1text">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <div>
                            <?php echo $content_parts['extended']; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

When the code above for `page.php` is used, `get_template_part('body', 'm')` does not work. It shows nothing. However, `get_template_part('ingress', 'm')` works.

## Works when...

... the code above is changed and `get_template_part` is not used. Meaning all the code is in `page.php`.

## So, ...

`get_template_part('body', 'm')` and `get_template_part( 'ingress', 'm')` can't be in two separate files.

**Any ideas why? And how to solve this problem?**

Comment: Long shot, but have you tried changing slug `body` to something else?

Comment: Thank you for commenting. Sorry, just tried it, and nothing happend.

Comment: Are all these files in the same directory?

Comment: That is correct. But problem was solved. Please see answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It helped to read my own question some times.

The problem is that the *fetching* and *receiving the content parts* are not being saved across files.

So all I needed to do was to write the following in the beginning of `body-m.php`:

```
<?php
// Fetch post content
    $content = get_post_field( 'post_content', get_the_ID() );

    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);

    // Get content parts
    $content_parts = get_extended( $content );
?>
```

**This solved the problem.**